# How can I insert sublayouts to QListWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, html, qt, user-interface

I want to create a list of downloads (like the firefox download list)
[image]
<sub>(source: [cybernetnews.com](https://cybernetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/firefox3downloadmanager1.jpg))</sub>

The problem is that I want to make a UI like that, but I dont really know how. I tried to create a QListWidget but with that I can only set text and an icon, I cant really add a sublayout. For example, I would want to have a sublayout like follows:

```
QVBoxLayout
    QLabel
    QHBoxLayout
        QProgressBar
        QPushButton
        QPushButton
    QLabel
```

How can I insert these sublayouts to QListWidgetItem?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear, what do you want - Qt application or web application,? What documentation you are talking about? P.S. Why do you think firefox downloads list is based on any html page?

Comment: The question is not clear at all. What do you want to do? What have you tried? What is confusing?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas is that better?

Comment: Well, this _was_ bad question, but it was fixed. I'd rescind my close vote, but I [had no possibility](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes). Now it is normal question and should be  reopened, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you have 3 separate alternatives:

1. Using QML. I've never developed smth using QtQuick, but it seems it provides tools for creating very complex layouts.
2. Using your own [item delegates](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html) for list items. The task of creating delegate, that should support some interactivity is relatively difficult, because you should redraw controls and send signals according to user actions by yourself.
3. Using `ListWidget`'s [`setItemWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget) for every item in your list. It is actually the simplest way (as I see it), but it may have some performance troubles on *really* long lists. In this case you just create widget with intended layout and set it to every item.